# asp.net mvc 4 issue with ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc4 project where i have filter form which based on @Ajax.BeginForm and when I check button in the bottom of the section loaded table with filtered elements where I have one column with dropdowns. And when I select one item of dropdown I want that in the closer columns loaded information based on ma select element, but select isnt into action when I select element. Its have an action when I apply my js script in the Console. My table rendered as partial view.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                    <select id="UniversityProgramId" name="UniversityProgramId">
                        <option disabled="disabled">Select program</option>
                        @foreach(var program in item.Program)
                        {
                            <option value="@program.ProgramId">@program.ProgramName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#UniversityProgramId').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Filter/ProgramCost/' + $('#UniversityProgramId').val(), function (data) {
                var items = data;
                $('#ProgramPrice').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Update, here is my JSonResult view inside filter controller

```
public JsonResult ProgramCost(int Id)
    {
        var model = _repo.GetPrograms().Where(x => x.ProgramId == Id).Select(x => x.Price);

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Is your AJAX call working? if you put a breakpoint on `var items = data`, are you getting data back? If so, what is it? You're working with JSON, so you're likely going to have to convert `data` into appropriate HTML structures.

Comment: @Chris update my question, problem is in the next: my jquery code isnt catch change event. And my ajax isnt work.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your error console? Errors will often halt javascript execution.

Comment: @Chris no actions, no errors, absolutely nothing, seems like this dropdown isnt exist on the page, which is very strange

Comment: Just noticed, you're deferring execution to the DOM twice: `$(document).ready(function () {` and `$(function () {` are doing the same thing. Can you remove one and see if that helps?

Comment: delete function, the same issue, request isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling .getJSON, but then placing the results into the HTML of the ProgramPrice.

If `/Filter/ProgramCost/' + $('#UniversityProgramId').val()` is returning JSON, then you'll need to traverse each element and create the HTML. I doubt you can just set the HTML using JSON values.

Comment: Update my question. In my ProgramPlace's element I have the next: <p id="ProgramPlace"></p>

Comment: The ID of the <p> is `ProgramPlace` however, in the JavaScript, you are referencing `ProgramPrice`

Comment: Also, here is an example of what it looks like when you do `.html()` on a list of integers, which I believe is what you are doing: http://jsfiddle.net/hwx8w/

Comment: My problem based on the next: I don't have any respons/request, nothing sended and nothing arrived. And about ProgramPlace< I'm misprint on the site, sory, in my code ProgramPrice